# How to Get queryset not dict django aggregate

Tags: python, django, django-orm

i'm using this queryset for my requirements

```
invoices = Invoice.objects.aggregate(total_amount=Sum('order__order_items__amount'),number_of_invoices=Count('pk', distinct=True))
```

which returns dict--->

```
{'total_amount': Decimal('17700.00'), 'number_of_invoices': 2}
```

but I want queryset how can i do that..
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

This is what aggregate do :)

You can add a `DecimalField` to `Invoice` model, that aggregates `total_amount` during before every save. I suggest signals for that.

###### apps.py

```
class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    ...

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

###### signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from .models import Invoice

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Invoice)
def total_amount_aggregation(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.total_amount = # aggregate desired amount here
```

You have to set similar signals for your `Order`, so if you change `Order` object, the related `Invoice` object will be recalculated.

After that `QuerySet` will stay as `QuerySet` and every object will have always caclulated field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [**`.aggregate(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate) use [**`.annotate(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) this will return a **QuerySet** with given expression

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Count

invoices = Invoice.objects.annotate(
            total_amount=Sum('order__order_items__amount'),
            number_of_invoices=Count('pk', distinct=True)
           )
```

then to get [**`Sum(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#sum) & [**`Count(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#id9) of field do like this `invoices[0].total_amount__sum` & `invoices[0].number_of_invoices__count`